# Comparing 3D surface plots in R obtained with plot_ly() and persp(): different outputs?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, visualization, plotly

I am trying to draw a 3D surface plot using plotly in R but cannot get the  x and y values to match the z ones correctly – unlike when using persp().

The example on the plotly website itself (https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/) returns a different output than when using persp().

```
kd <- with(MASS::geyser, MASS::kde2d(duration, waiting, n = 50))

# with plotly
plot_ly(x = ~kd$x, y = ~kd$y, z = ~kd$z) %>% add_surface()

# with persp
persp(x = kd$x, y = kd$y, z = kd$z, theta=130, phi=40, r = sqrt(10), d = 3, ticktype = “detailed”)
```

In the 'plotly for R' book, it says *"there should be a sensible ordering to the x/y axes in a surface plot since plotly.js interpolates z values."*
I expect the issue to emerge from that but I cannot figure out how to solve it, except manually inverting x and y:

```
plot_ly(x = ~kd$y, y = ~kd$x, z = ~kd$z) %>% add_surface()
```

Is there a way to get the correct output with plot_ly directly, i.e. looking similar to the one with persp()?

[See the different output side by side here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SJCe.png)